# Passing User Credentials to Exchange

Tags: c#, authentication, exchange-server, ntlm

My scenario:

```
User -> Web App (ASP.NET, C# 3.5) -> Exchange
```

I need to pass the user's Window's account information to Exchange since it uses WIA.

I've enabled "NTLM" on my web app's properties and then I use:

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

It doesn't seem to be working.  Is DefaultNetworkCredentials the right way to go or should I use some other method to pass the user's credentials to Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to impersonate the current user first to do this. You can do this with a `WindowsImpersonationContext` or by setting the entire app to impersonate in your web.config file.

Comment: Thanks, but this hasn't solved the problem.  It still doesn't work.  I keep reading online about the "double-hop" NTLM problem.  Is this related or is there still a way to accomplish my scenario using NTLM?  Thanks.